# how to display a pop up message on clicking a button in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an application in Windows Phone 7 where i have a button which when clicked i want to display a pop up message which again will contain 3 buttons. Can anyone please tell me how to display this pop up message which will contain 3 buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in `xaml`. You can add a `Popup` tag and in between that tag, you may add a `StackPanel` which contains a text message and 3-4 buttons as you want. A snippet to that I found so far:

```
<Popup x:Name="my_popup_xaml" Grid.Row="2">
    <Border  BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
      <StackPanel Background="LightBlue">
        <Image Source="/Images/disclaimer.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,15,0,5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Disclaimer" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Margin="10,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="This is a pop-up window to display disclaimer" FontSize="21" Margin="10,0" />                      
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
          <Button x:Name="btn_continue"  Content="continue" Width="215" Click="btn_continue_Click"/>
          <Button x:Name="btn_cancel"    Content="cancel"   Width="215" Click="btn_cancel_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

You can add multiple `buttons` as per requirements because we are going to add them in a `StackPanel`.

well to make it work, you need to add Reference **`Microsoft.Phone.Controls`** in your project.

Pop up can be displayed through code, but I recommend to use xaml instead of code; its easy to implement!

To know more about it you can hit [**`THIS LINK`**](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone)

To make it more advanced, like, to save the state of Pop up you can check [**`THIS LINK`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456394.aspx)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little outdated, but you can use [WPAssets](http://wpassets.codeplex.com/).

You can call the MessageBox like this :

```
    private void buttonAny_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotificationTool.Show(
            "Custom",
            "Click on any of the buttons below.",
            new NotificationAction("Xxx", () => { }),
            new NotificationAction("Xxx", () => { }),
            new NotificationAction("Zzz", () => { }));
    }
```

Sample from the source of the project.

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way without including any library or other module. Is it possible with normal C# coding

Comment: You can have on or two. I dont think you can have more.

Comment: Can u please say then how to use WPassets